# How to use windbg to troubleshoot executable which won't start?

Tags: windbg

The [Intel Power Gadget](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20) tool will not run on my system, and I'm trying to figure out why.  It's a Core i7-720QM running Window 8.1 x64.  AIDA64 reads the CPU temperatures just fine, but I can't even launch the Intel Power Gadget.  No windows open and nothing happens.  It works fine on a different computer.

I tried attaching **windbg**, but it's not obvious what's causing the executable to fail.  I haven't been able to find a **windbg** tutorial which shows how to troubleshoot executables which won't start.

In the following output, I set a breakpoint and dumped the stack as recommended by user [blabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622813/blabb).  Any ideas?

```
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .restart
CommandLine: "C:\Program Files\Intel\Power Gadget 3.0\IntelPowerGadget.exe"

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: srv*
ModLoad: 00007ff6`800f0000 00007ff6`80178000   IntelPowerGadget.exe
ModLoad: 00007ff9`82ab0000 00007ff9`82c5c000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`80480000 00007ff9`805be000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7fcd0000 00007ff9`7fde5000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`550e0000 00000000`55643000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mfc100u.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`55920000 00000000`559f2000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCR100.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`80820000 00007ff9`80997000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`82450000 00007ff9`825a1000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`80ce0000 00007ff9`821f9000   C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`805c0000 00007ff9`80754000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7b660000 00007ff9`7b810000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17415_none_932b3b5547500489\gdiplus.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`55880000 00000000`55918000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP100.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`823f0000 00007ff9`82444000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7d8c0000 00007ff9`7db3b000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.17415_none_6240486fecbd8abb\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7cca0000 00007ff9`7cca7000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`803d0000 00007ff9`8047a000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`82700000 00007ff9`82911000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`825b0000 00007ff9`826f1000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`807c0000 00007ff9`80819000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
(1a58.1a54): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff9`82b71cd0 cc              int     3
0:000> bp ntdll!ntTerminateProcess
0:000> bl
 0 e 00007ff9`82b41090     0001 (0001)  0:**** ntdll!NtTerminateProcess
0:000> g
ModLoad: 00007ff9`80770000 00007ff9`807a6000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`80270000 00007ff9`803c3000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7e870000 00007ff9`7e999000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7df70000 00007ff9`7df91000   C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`550d0000 00000000`550dd000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MFC100ENU.DLL
ModLoad: 00007ff9`82a00000 00007ff9`82aaa000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`743b0000 00007ff9`743c1000   C:\Program Files\Intel\Power Gadget 3.0\EnergyLib64.dll
ModLoad: 00007ff9`7f230000 00007ff9`7f276000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\POWRPROF.dll
Breakpoint 0 hit
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess:
00007ff9`82b41090 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
0:000> kb
RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00007ff9`82b1f400 : 00007e42`e1a67e08 00000000`013f1680 00000000`00000000 00000000`00fafc80 : ntdll!NtTerminateProcess
00007ff9`8048516a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`013f1680 00000000`013f1680 00007ff6`80105bb0 : ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x60
00000000`55940ccd : 00000000`013f1678 00007ff6`863f6e0b 00000000`01181f9e 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xa
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for IntelPowerGadget.exe
00007ff6`800f9e78 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : MSVCR100!doexit+0x1c1
00007ff9`804813d2 : 00007ff6`800f9fc4 00007ff6`7f50b000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : IntelPowerGadget+0x9e78
00007ff9`82b1eb64 : 00007ff9`804813b0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess:
00007ff9`82b41090 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
0:000> g
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xa:
00007ff9`82b4109a c3              ret
```

Comment: You might want to try using Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to see if there's a problem accessing a file or registry entry that might be leading to the failure.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Intel\Power >Gadget 3.0\EnergyLib64.dll` is a strange file name (including a >). Maybe something went wrong with code formatting. Could you try to paste the ouput just as it appears in WinDbg, please? After pasting the text, there is a button to format it as code.

Comment: WinDbg shows module loads of modules which it could load, but not the ones that were not loaded. In case of missing files, Process Monitor is the right tool. Add a filter for `IntelPowerGadget.exe`. Export as XML and try [ProcMonAnalyzer](http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/). That tool can sort DLLs by the number of tries it took to load a DLL. Usually a high count indicates that something is wrong.

Comment: You may also want to give [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) a try. It won't tell you anything ProcMon doesn't, but the interface is a bit friendlier for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks. There was a typo in my first post.  The `>` should not have been in the filename. I accidentally inserted that character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the output in your query is not useful you are simply running the application and windbg is showing all the modules it loaded  which doesnt yield any information to the problem in hand you may need to set atleast one breakpoint let windbg break and dump the stack to analyze the path of execution

**.restart**
when windbg breaks set a bp prior to issuing g when the breakpoint is hit dump the stack backtrace with kb
**bp ntdll!ntTerminateProcess

bl

g

kb**

edit your post to paste the new output

the function that lead to termination appears to be at 00007ff6`800f9e78

you may need to analyze this function

`ub (unassemble backward )` **ub 00007ff6`800f9e78**  enabling loadersnap !gflag + sls and scanning the debug spew for clues could lead to failures due to dependency  should show the call if this call appears to be a terminal call you may need to trace back to determine the branch which leads to this call and analyse why this branch was taken

```
00007ff6`800f9e78 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : MSVCR100!doexit+0x1c1
00007ff9`804813d2 : 00007ff6`800f9fc4 00007ff6`7f50b000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : IntelPowerGadget+0x9e78
```

edit

i took a look at the offending exe it seems there is an integer division by zero exception in  EnergyLib64.dll->Initialization Routine called by initterm (LdrpRunInitializeRoutine) when it checks for some processor specific functionality using cpuid  the result of cpuid after some calculations is shifted right by 20 shr eax,20 which makes eax 0 and the divisor ebp is also 0 so div eax, ebp results in a divide by zero exception which leads to immediate termination. via msvcrt!exit at 0x......9e78

Comment: Thanks.  I did this and edited my question to include the output.

Comment: Learning something new every day but I would try the Procmon route first. It takes far less time to try than trying to work backwards why doexit got called.

Comment: yes windbg should be used only when all other options have been exhausted.

Comment: Looking at your latest edit, OP might use `sxe` after `.restart` to confirm your analysis I suppose?

Comment: @blabb: Thanks for your thorough investigation.  I learned a lot.  I got in touch with the utility's author.  It turns out that my CPU is not supported.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers sxe ld energy* will stop after Section is Mapped now setting a breakpoint in ntdll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutine and executing pc (run until next call) a few times should get you the Initialization routine in energylib64.dll   ntdll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines+0x4d5:

00000000`78edef71 ffd6            call    rsi {EnergyLib64!GetPowerData+0x2a60 (00000001`80007710)}
step inside the call and trace until exception

Comment: @Slack yes it is failing when trying to ascertain extended topology leaf EAX = 0xb ecx = 0x1 branch of cpuid